How to use WebProxy with Autodesk.Authentication using C#?
I was using Autodesk.forge and we have web proxy setting for this, but it is deprecated and replaced by Autodesk.authentication and i am not able to find any option to use a web proxy
I was using the below code with Autodesk.Forge
TwoLeggedApi oauth = new TwoLeggedApi();
IEnvironment env = Global.GlobalData.Environment;
if (env.ProxySettings.proxyAddr != "")
{
    oauth.Configuration.ApiClient.RestClient.Proxy = new WebProxy(env.ProxySettings.proxyAddr);
    oauth.Configuration.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10;
}

I am using the below code with Autodesk.authentication and it's working without webproxy,
SDKManager sdkManager = SdkManagerBuilder
    .Create() // Creates SDK Manager Builder itself.
    .Build();

AuthenticationClient authenticationClient = new AuthenticationClient(sdkManager);
TwoLeggedToken twoLeggedToken = await authenticationClient.GetTwoLeggedTokenAsync(client_id,   client_secret, new List<Scopes>() { Scopes.DataRead, Scopes.BucketRead });

Please suggest what options we have to use web proxy.

Hi, the new SDK does not currently have an option to use a web proxy similar to the earlier one. I would however be interested to understand more of your workflow, and the usage of the proxy.
